# $\sin( a\arcsin(x))$ in terms of rational functions and radicals

Tags: trigonometry

By letting
$$ \theta = a \arcsin(x) \, ,
$$
$$
x = \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{a}\right)$$
If $\theta / a$ is the angle in a right triangle then the hypotenuse of length $1$, and the opposite side $x$. I want to find $\sin(\theta)$ as $ \theta = a \arcsin(x)$.

For $a = 2$ and $a = 4$ this is quite simple. When $a = 2$:
$$\sin(\theta) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
As $\theta/2$ is the angle in our triangle we can simply substitute this in terms of $x$ So
$$ \sin(\theta) = \sin(2 \arcsin(x)) = 2x\sqrt{1 -x^2}$$
repeating this process for $a = 4$
$$ \sin(\theta) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = 4 \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\left( 2 \cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right) -a\right)$$
In other terms
$$\sin(4 \arcsin(x)) =4x\sqrt{1- x^2} (1-2x^2) $$
How can I attempt to generalise this at least for even values of $a$, thanks.